# VB.NET: Multiple events - How to call function only once?

Tags: vb.net, events

A have a dozen of checkboxes to filter data in DataGridView. They all look more or less so:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
      filter1=CheckBox1.Checked
      Do_Filter()
    End Sub
```

I have also a button "Set all":

```
    Private Sub SetAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetAll.Click
      CheckBox1.Checked = True
      CheckBox2.Checked = True
      ' etc... 12 times
    End Sub
```

All works fine. The only problem is that Do_Filter() procedure is called 12 times... Any idea how to postpone Do_Filter() invocation and do it only once at the very end of SetAll_Click() ?

Comment: Have a boolean form variable.  Set it at the start of your setall click method, check it in the Do_Filter and exit if true,  then the last line in serall_click before do_filter, set the flag to false

Comment: You have to clarify your question. So you have a CheckBox and Do_Filter() method called if it was changed. And you have method setting all CheckBoxes to true and only there you want to call Do_Filter() once. In other cases - you still need this Do_Filter() to be called

Comment: Hursey: Argh... sometimes simplest solutions are hardest to notice... This was so obvious. :-)

Comment: @micha, confirming one of the answers you can get +2 reputation ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may introduce a boolean variable:

```
Private doFilterEnabled As Boolean = True
```

Add if statement here:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
  filter1=CheckBox1.Checked
  If doFilterEnabled Then
      Do_Filter()
  End If  
End Sub
```

And small fix here:

```
Private Sub SetAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SetAll.Click
  doFilterEnabled  = False
  CheckBox1.Checked = True
  CheckBox2.Checked = True
  ' etc... 12 times
  Do_Filter()
  doFilterEnabled  = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Or, in the alternative, put the check in `Do_Filter`.  You'll still have the method calls, but skip the (presumably) expensive processing.  (If it's not expensive, then it might not be worth the effort to avoid the extra calls.)